# How to read data from csv file that has line breaks

Tags: imacros

I have example data in csv file

> 1. Some text
> 2. Text 2
> 3. Text 3

I want to output it with line break into text area, but getting error when trying to put it as it is.
it works only when i remove line breaks

```
iimPlayCode('ADD !EXTRACT {{!COL1}}\n');
var description = iimGetExtract(1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit your csv file by adding double quotes:

> "1. Some text
> 2. Text 2 
> 3. Text 3"

And run the code:

```
iimPlayCode('SET !DATASOURCE yourfile.txt\nADD !EXTRACT {{!COL1}}');
var description = iimGetExtract(1);
```